# Дан радиус окружности R. Написать программу нахождения длины... Не понимаю в чем ошибка

Tags: c++

прохожу курс на stepic, есть такое задание: *Дан радиус окружности R. Написать программу нахождения длины и площади данной окружности. Считать, что радиус является вещественным числом, а Пи = 3.14. Ответ выводится с точностью до 2 цифры после запятой.*

Написал следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float R, pi=3.14, length, s;
    cin >> R;
    length = (pi*2)*R;
    R = pow(R, 2);
    s = (pi)*(R);
    
    cout << length << " " << s;

    return 0;
}
```

Но проверку не проходит. в чем может быть проблема в коде? вдруг где-то ошибься?

Comment: "Ответ выводится с точностью до 2 цифры после запятой." - где?

Comment: подключал #include <iomanip>,setprecision(2). но тоже не проходит проверку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На степике четко написано:

> точность можно задать следующим образом:
> `cout << fixed << setprecision(i) << x`
> где i - количество цифр после запятой для выражения x.

И код

```
cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << length << " " << s;
```

вполне проходит проверку...

Comment: Плюс, не нужны эти лишние  объявления и предварительные расчеты.  Можно объявить только float Pi = 3.14, R; и вывести   cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << 2 * Pi * R << '\n' << Pi * R * R;

Answer (score 0):

Невнимательно читал условие.
Решение:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float R, pi=3.14, length, s;
    cin >> R;
    length = (pi*2)*R;
    R = pow(R, 2);
    s = (pi)*(R);
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << length << " ";
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << s;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вторые `<< fixed << setprecision(2)` излишни, это `setw` сбрасывается после очередного вывода, а эти остаются действующими.